# how to calculate shortest distance between two moving objects

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

the question is simple one object is moving from **east-west** with a velocity of `v1` and another from **south-north** with velocity `v2`.

I just need the algorithm(formula) to calculate the shortest distance between them so I can write a program for it.

I do have distance between them and the meting point of their paths they are d1 and d2.

Comment: The shortest distance between 2 objects is a straight line. When traveling perpendicular to each other that line should be the hypotenuse of the triangle formed by joining the points.

Comment: Ya but its changing over time and I need the shortest between them.

Comment: So that's constant v for both objects no or constant acceleration and you know the elapsed time?

Comment: no acceleration ,just constant speed v1 and v2

Comment: You want the closest that the two objects will ever be to each other? Do you know the positions at some point (eg t=0; the start) in time as well as the velocities?

Comment: Set up mathematical functions mapping the time to the position of both objects. Then, apply Pythagoras to determine the distance over time. Then, apply usual methods to find minima of that function. This has nothing to do with programming, this is just mathematics.

Comment: @moreON sorry I forgot yes I do have distance between the meting point of their paths they are d1 and d2

Comment: What do `d1` and `d2` represent?  I am reluctant to update my answer because you are not being clear.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen since both are traveling in south-north and west-east so their path will meet at a point say P ,d1 and d2 is the distance between both objects and point P when t=0.

Comment: At which time are the two points at vector `d1` and `d2` ?

Comment: t=0 when distance is d1 and d2

Comment: see my answer, @user3452098, it should solve your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are asking for 2-d space, at `t=0`, let the starting points be `(d1,0) and (0,d2)` on the coordinate axes. We can assume this because one object is always moving horizontally (E-W direction, along X-axis) and other vertically (S-N direction, along Y-axis). Now, after some time `t`, their positions will be,`(d1-t*v1)` and `(0,d2-t*v2)`. (Speed-Distance-Time relation).

Now, distance between them at this time `t` will be,

```
D = d^2 = (d1-t*v1)^2 + (d2-t*v2)^2
```

So, differentiating both sides wrt `t`,

```
dD/dt = 2(-v1)(d1-t*v1) + 2(-v2)(d2-t*v2)   ....(1)
```

For D to be minimum, `dD/dt = 0` and second differential must be positive. Now, second differential :

```
d2D/dt2 = 2*v1^2 + 2*v2^2 which is positive for all real v1/v2. So, if `dD/dt = 0`, distance will be minimum.
```

So, equating (1) = 0, we get

```
t = (d1v1 + d2v2)/(v1^2 + v2^2)
```

So, get `sqrt(D)` at `t = --above value--` and that shall be your answer.

PS: ask these type of questions on mathematics stackexchange.

Comment: Thank-you for your explanation

Comment: If this answers your problem, accept the answer.There are too many unaccepted answers on stackoverflow that waste time of users who try and answer them. :)

Comment: already done,I I know even many of my answers have never been excepted but left with thanks.